# Webpack / ES6 dynamic import

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6 dynamic import to load a Sass file, according to an environment variable.

It's working fine, but when I build the production directory with Webpack, all the Sass files are exported as a JS chunk in the build directory.

After some research, I finally understand that import() look for similar files with the same path (only when I put a variable in the import)

It's quite problematic, I'd like to get the correct Sass file exported, and not the others.

```
import(`./assets/scss/App.${brandName}.scss`)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: I don't think you can do that. 'Importing' non-js files is a webpack thing distinct from the browser's `import` statement/dynamic import function. So unless you're using webpack *at runtime* (bad idea) there's no way dynamically load non-js resources that way.

Comment: Heh, I was wrong. You apparently can do it, via webpack "magic comments". See [this post](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234) for details.

Comment: @JaredSmith Yes, I tried them. webpackInclude and webpackExclude seem to be the solution, but can't make them work. Don't understand why ... I tried with very simple regex, and still not working ...

Comment: Look, I'm not telling you *not* to do this, but don't do this. Unless you are trying to push the bleeding edge of what the tools are capable of, just import the scss statically.

Comment: @JaredSmith Actually, I have 3 sass files, one per theme. But maybe in the future, there will be more themes. So I'd like to import them dynamically, rather than import each of them one by one.
In fact, dynamic import function works fine. I just want one file to be imported, not all of them.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, you can't do that!

Because import statement must be at the top. Thus, you cannot define the variable before import statement. Hence, you cannot utilize the variable in import statements.

---

But, you can trick to use like this:

```
import brandName from 'your_path_to_brandName_export'
import(`./assets/scss/App.${brandName}.scss`)
```

---

**Update**

I am not sure about dynamic import, but it might help you further. See this [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import):

```
<script type="module">
  import * as module from './utils.mjs';
  module.default();
  // → logs 'Hi from the default export!'
  module.doStuff();
  // → logs 'Doing stuff…'
</script>
```

See this [source](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/11/dynamic-import) for further help.

Hope, this helps!

Comment: Most browsers have implemented dynamic import, the problem is that importing non-js resources that way is specific to webpack, which is generally not running inside your browser at runtime.